# Chasing up "ORA-01084: invalid argument in OCI call"

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I've got here enterprise project with .net 4.0 c#, IBatisNet and CSLA framework.

One of project jobs is failing with `ORA-01084: invalid argument in OCI call` when calling insert proc in a package. Error message returned is cryptic at best, the stored proc has 83 input parameters which aren't bound by name (thanks to IBatis).

What is curious: I've got a set of records let's say `Order` and `OrderItems`. `Order` has 28 order items. The job has to renew the order by creating another `Order` and copying all `OrderItems` records. New order items are referencing the old order items by `ParentOrderItemId` field, which is also a selection criteria for `Orders` due to be renewed.

When I run it first time the process blows on `OrderItemId: 12345` with `ORA-01084` error. But when I rerun it next time, it successfully process `OrderItemId: 12345`. And then blows up on `OrderItemId: 12444`. I then rerun and it processes `OrderItemId: 12444` correctly and so on and so forth.

I've got logs of DbParameters passed in they are the same in both cases.

I've got oci client trace, but it's not useful either.

I've setup logging on a database layer, and so far it's giving me nothing.

Any ideas how to trace those type of errors?

Comment: vague idea: if the parameters passed into the OCI call are the same on the first failed and second successful execution (as you said can be seen in log of DbParameters), there could be some sort of initialisation error, possibly involving null values.

Comment: When you say "logging on database layer", does that mean the stored procedure logs the input parameters, so you could verify there happened no mismatch of column values somewhere?

Comment: yep, I've added thorough logging everywhere so that I can see whatever is passed in and out in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess after all these years I need to provide an answer.

The issue lies deep in Oracle .Net drivers. We had Qty field defined as an INT. Due to internal architecture Qty could be negative or null. 95% of cases Qty was positive integer (as it should be), but sometimes due to adjustments and other factors it could be null or negative.

So in the end I traced it to the order of how you put your records into the database:

Qty 1
Qty 0
Qty null 
Qty -1

works correctly.

But in this case:

Qty null
Qty 1
Qty -1

will blow with OCI invalid argument on "-1" value.

I created a ticket on Oracle, and send it down to our product team to fix. Since then I moved on, so not too sure if and when was it fixed.

Comment: Just tried 12c ODP.Net and the bug seems to still be there. So it seems they have not fixed it, as we can duplicate it consistently in our application.

Comment: My project was rather small at the time, so I didn't chase it down with Oracle. If you guys have the time and Oracle support plan you can try to push it along. Either that, or a kludge with QTY being Non nullable.

Comment: We don't have the time :).  Anyway, I did find that when we use the new Managed Oracle dll we do not experience the bug (e.g. this is the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll).  So the problem appears to be limited to the unmanaged versions of the dll (e.g. Oracle.DataAccess.dll).  Anyway, thanks for your post on this, it's always good to know somebody else is having the same problem you are :).

Answer (score 6):

I was receiving this same error message. In my case it was because I was passing an empty string to a CLOB column. Normally I would pass a large XML document but sometimes there was no document. Now, I check for empty string and write "empty".

Comment: Hi, thank you! Your answer solved my issue. There is a CLOB field, like ERROMSG, I filled this CLOB field with empty string '' and then I got this error. I changed my code to replace '' to 'empty' (as suggested by @user3498708) and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I just encountered this error.  The issue was an incorrect `OracleType` in one of my parameters.  The type was set at a `NVarchar` and the database column had been changed to a `Clob`.

Try to explicitly define your parameter OracleType.

```
OracleParameter(string name, OracleType oracleType)
```

Answer (score -1):

A nullable column with the data type `nchar(2)` was the problem for me.
It does not accept null, but requires some values to be passed in while inserting data.

Comment: This would've probably been a much better answer if you've provided an example.